# Vbscript to split excel column data inexcel into 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I am trying to split the data in excel sheet which is like this:

```
|a a    1|
|b b    2|
|c c    3|
|d d d  4|
```

to

```
|a a| 1|
|b b| 2|
|c c| 3|
|d d d| 4|
```

I've observed a pattern like if there is more than one space in between the characters of any particular cell(or row), they should be split into seperate columns.

Comment: So far i have tried this code: [Click me](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/VB_Script/Q_28433393.html) (appologies i could not paste the code here) .Bt this doesnot get close to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a regular expression to replace sequences of 2 or more consecutive spaces with a tab, and then use the [`TextToColumns`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) method to split the column in two:

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True

Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\path\to\your.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "  +"

For Each cell In ws.UsedRange
  cell.Value = re.Replace(cell.Value, vbTab)
Next

ws.UsedRange.TextToColumns
```

Comment: Works like a charm!! Accepted as answer!

Comment: One more question here: I am actually trying to convert a text file to excel and then modify that excel with this code. In this process it does not save automatically ( I have added xl.ActiveWorkbook.Save) When i manually do it it says do you want to save filename.txt again.Can you help me on this

Comment: You need to use [`SaveAs()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) with the correct fileformat specifier if you want to save the file in a different format.

Answer (score 1):

Use a RegExp that looks for

1. a sequence of Not-\ns non-greedily
2. before a non-empty sequence of whitespace
3. followed by digits

As in:

```
Option Explicit

Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function

Dim r : Set r = New RegExp
r.Pattern = "^(.+?)\s+(\d+)$"
Dim s, m
For Each s In Split("a a    1|d d d  4", "|")
    Set m = r.Execute(s)(0)
    WScript.Echo qq(m.Submatches(0)), qq(m.Submatches(1))
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 31160562.vbs
"a a" "1"
"d d d" "4"
```

Comment: any way to give the contents of fnc split() dynamically?

Comment: @KrishKrishna - sorry, I don't understand "give the contents of fnc split() dynamically".

Comment: If you split on two spaces you could get the two groups separated, but if there are more than two spaces between `"a a"`  and `"1"` you would also get blank values inbetween: `Split(STRING, Space(2))`

Answer (score 1):

you can write a function which uses the Split function based on the space,

below is the code snippet which feel will work for u

```
    Dim arrVar
    strCelldata = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
    arrVar = Split(strCelldata, "  ")
    j = 2
    For Each arrVal In arrVar
        If Trim(arrVal) <> "" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, j) = arrVal
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next
```

you may need to add one more for loop to go thru all the data available on the excel sheet.